# Any way to do mathematical operations in calculated field of Data Studio?

Tags: looker-studio, calculated-field

I'm trying to create a calculated field with the following calculation:

```
CASE
 WHEN Number = 5 THEN Searchvolume / Number + 33.9
 WHEN Number = 6 THEN Searchvolume / Number + 16.28
 WHEN Number = 9 THEN Searchvolume / Number + 10.36
 ELSE Searchvolume / Number
END
```

On doing this i get an error `THEN/ELSE statements cannot contain functions or mathematical operations.`

Is there any other possibility to accomplish this calculation as calculated field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### 0) Summary

Use **EITHER** #1 or #2 below

### 1) [`CASE`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7020724)

For future reference, the [11 Mar 2021 Update](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/10331528#mar-11-2021) included enhancements to **Conditional Expressions** in [`CASE`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7020724) statements, thus, the [`CASE`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7020724) statement in the question now works as expected:

```
CASE
  WHEN Number = 5 THEN Searchvolume / Number + 33.9
  WHEN Number = 6 THEN Searchvolume / Number + 16.28
  WHEN Number = 9 THEN Searchvolume / Number + 10.36
  ELSE Searchvolume / Number
END
```

### 2) [`IF`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/10468770)

Alternatively a **Nested** [`IF`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/10468770) **Conditional Expression** (introduced in the [11 Mar 2021 Update](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/10331528#mar-11-2021)) would do the trick:

```
IF(Number = 5, Searchvolume / Number + 33.9, 
IF(Number = 6, Searchvolume / Number + 16.28, 
IF(Number = 9, Searchvolume / Number + 10.36, 
Searchvolume / Number)))
```

[Editable Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/9004efc0-c5a6-41ff-b7ce-6366fca4cadf) (Embedded [Google Sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1s9J3gquYLG68g7Nmvks9T58ZEFUifrcpfxu-TZoIUkg/edit?usp=sharing) Data Source) and a GIF to elaborate:

[image]